# Extra-terrestrial equivalent meaning other time rather than other world

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word similar to extra-terrestrial, only meaning other time(like past or future) rather than other planet?

example;

> He is **from another time**

The bolded portion is what I want to replace with the other word.

Comment: There's **non-contemporaneous**  (Not occurring at the same time; _not of the same date or period_) ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/non-contemporaneous)), but it doesn't flow too smoothly, and is usually used in overt comparisons.

Comment: [Otherworldly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/otherworldly) is not usually taken literally. It can be used to describe someone who isn't in quite the same domain as most people.

Comment: There's ***extratemporal***, which as well as applying to [*tissue located in an area of the brain other than the temporal lobe*](https://www.webmd.com/epilepsy/guide/extratemporal-cortical-resection#:~:text=Extratemporal%20means%20the%20tissue%20is,other%20than%20the%20temporal%20lobe.&text=In%20some%20cases%2C%20tissue%20may,area%2Flobe%20of%20the%20brain.), can also be used to mean ***outside of, or forming no part of, the sequence of time*** (that latter definition is from the full OED).

Comment: We say [*He was born before his time*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ahead-of-your-time#:~:text=If%20someone%20is%20ahead%20of,think%20in%20the%20same%20way.&text=His%20only%20fundamental%20mistake%2C%20he,20%20years%20before%20his%20time.) to mean they have new ideas a long time before other people start to think in the same way. But idiomatically, I don't think *He was born **after** his time* is so often used to mean he would have fitted in better if he'd lived in an earlier age / society (it certainly does occur though).

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Belonging to an earlier age" may describe someone of the latter type - rather like Jacob Rees Mogg - sometimes referred to as "Minister for the Eighteenth Century".

Comment: Your title, coupled with the prepositional phrase in your example, seems to demand an adjective. Is this your intention?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, yes, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The first term that has come to my mind with that meaning is *time traveler*.

Cambridge dictionary:

**someone who can move between different times in the past or the future**

An example from Lexico:

‘A Victorian time traveller would recognise the schools more than any other institution in this age.’

I would say this is one of the main terms used to describe this kind of people. *Time travel* is the common collocation to talk about travelling through time, so *time traveler* would be the natural derivative form.

Comment: I've changed the message. I tried to make a comparison between different terms to see their use, but the thing is I can't find any other similar terms to make it. I can't judge popularity then. Thanks for the correction.